# Swap values using pointers in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int x = 197;
    int y = 208;

    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);

    swap(&x, &y);

    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}

void swap(int* a, int* b) {

    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b
    *b = temp; //invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'int *')

}
```

Why does the last line give that error?

Comment: Missing semicolon on the previous line.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: why not using void swap(int& x, int& y)? - it works faster 

also , if u want to swap "C data types",  use x ^= y ^= x ^= y; also much faster.

inline - would help your perfonace too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {

    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b; // missing semicolon!
    *b = temp;

}
```

Comment: Don't bother posting an answer to trivial typos. Just post a comment and vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

```
*a = *b
*b = temp;
```

Is the same as

```
*a = *b * b = temp;
//   ^^^^^^
```

you cannot multiply a int with a pointer

Comment: Don't waste time posting answers to obvious typos. Just post a comment and vote to close.

Comment: I thought the analysis of how the compiler saw the error was interesting.